# Convert Pine Script v1 or v2 to v4

Tags: pine-script

Please see below an indicator I found on Trading View. My goal is to combine it with other indicators or oscillators to develop a trading strategy.

Since other indicators are made using the Pine Script version 4, I need to make sure that this indicator is compatible with version 4. When I add //@version=4 on top, it gives an error. It looks like there is something wrong with the vswitch21 part. Could anybody please help me to fix this?

Many thanks

```
//@version=4
study(title="Volatility Switch [LazyBear]", shorttitle="VOLSWITCH_LB")
dr= roc(close,1)/sma(close,2)
dummy=input(false, title="------- Choose lengths below ----"), il21=input(true, title="21"), il14=input(false, title="14")

vola21=stdev(dr, 21)
vswitch21=((vola21[1] <= vola21 ) + (vola21[2] <= vola21 ) +   (vola21[3] <= vola21 ) +   
        (vola21[4] <= vola21 ) +  (vola21[5] <= vola21 ) + (vola21[6] <= vola21 ) +   
        (vola21[7] <= vola21 ) +  (vola21[8] <= vola21 ) +  (vola21[9] <= vola21 ) +  
        (vola21[10] <= vola21 ) + (vola21[11] <= vola21 ) +  (vola21[12] <= vola21 ) +  
        (vola21[13] <= vola21 ) +  (vola21[14] <= vola21 ) +  (vola21[15] <= vola21 ) +  
        (vola21[16] <= vola21 ) +  (vola21[17] <= vola21 ) +  (vola21[18] <= vola21 ) +  
        (vola21[19] <= vola21 ) +  (vola21[20] <= vola21 ) + 1) / 21

vola14=stdev(dr, 14)
vswitch14=((vola14[1] <= vola14 ) + (vola14[2] <= vola14 ) +   (vola14[3] <= vola14 ) +   
        (vola14[4] <= vola14 ) +  (vola14[5] <= vola14 ) + (vola14[6] <= vola14 ) +   
        (vola14[7] <= vola14 ) +  (vola14[8] <= vola14 ) +  (vola14[9] <= vola14 ) +  
        (vola14[10] <= vola14 ) + (vola14[11] <= vola14 ) +  (vola14[12] <= vola14 ) +  
        (vola14[13] <= vola14 ) + 1) / 14 
 
hline(0.5, title="Median")
plot(il21?vswitch21:na, color=red, linewidth=2, title="VOLSWITCH_21")
plot(il14?vswitch14:na, color=green, linewidth=2, title="VOLSWITCH_14")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several changes that need to be made:

1. In v1, any indent outside of a function is considered to be a continuation of a line. In v4, only indents not divisible by 4 are considered line continuations. Both `vswitch21` and `vswitch14` are a single long line, so you'd need to use an indent that is not a multiple of 4.
2. Both variables include additions of `bool` values. In v4, it is no longer possible to do addition on `bool` values, so you'd need to convert them to `int`.
3. Color constants `red` and `green` were renamed to `color.red` and `color.green`.

Working code:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Volatility Switch [LazyBear]", shorttitle="VOLSWITCH_LB")
dr= roc(close,1)/sma(close,2)
dummy=input(false, title="------- Choose lengths below ----"), il21=input(true, title="21"), il14=input(false, title="14")

// bool to int
b2i(_bool) =>
    _bool ? 1 : 0

vola21=stdev(dr, 21)
vswitch21=(b2i(vola21[1] <= vola21 ) + b2i(vola21[2] <= vola21 ) + b2i(vola21[3] <= vola21 ) +   
 b2i(vola21[4] <= vola21 ) + b2i(vola21[5] <= vola21 ) + b2i(vola21[6] <= vola21 ) +   
 b2i(vola21[7] <= vola21 ) + b2i(vola21[8] <= vola21 ) + b2i(vola21[9] <= vola21 ) +  
 b2i(vola21[10] <= vola21 ) + b2i(vola21[11] <= vola21 ) + b2i(vola21[12] <= vola21 ) +  
 b2i(vola21[13] <= vola21 ) + b2i(vola21[14] <= vola21 ) + b2i(vola21[15] <= vola21 ) +  
 b2i(vola21[16] <= vola21 ) + b2i(vola21[17] <= vola21 ) + b2i(vola21[18] <= vola21 ) +  
 b2i(vola21[19] <= vola21 ) + b2i(vola21[20] <= vola21 ) + 1) / 21

vola14=stdev(dr, 14)
vswitch14=(b2i(vola14[1] <= vola14) + b2i(vola14[2] <= vola14 ) + b2i(vola14[3] <= vola14 ) +   
 b2i(vola14[4] <= vola14 ) + b2i(vola14[5] <= vola14 ) + b2i(vola14[6] <= vola14 ) +   
 b2i(vola14[7] <= vola14 ) + b2i(vola14[8] <= vola14 ) + b2i(vola14[9] <= vola14 ) +  
 b2i(vola14[10] <= vola14 ) + b2i(vola14[11] <= vola14 ) + b2i(vola14[12] <= vola14 ) +  
 b2i(vola14[13] <= vola14 ) + 1) / 14 
 
hline(0.5, title="Median")
plot(il21?vswitch21:na, color=color.red, linewidth=2, title="VOLSWITCH_21")
plot(il14?vswitch14:na, color=color.green, linewidth=2, title="VOLSWITCH_14")
```